# Take user input sentence/string and compare items in the list and return list entry if keyword in sentence matches with list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a list

```
List1 = ['Cappuccino','Café Latte','Expresso','Macchiato ','Irish coffee ']
```

I have to take input sentence from user and if any of the word matches from List1 should return the string from that list1 along with some legend .

Example: Enter your input string :
User Input : `I want 1 Cappuccino.`
Expected output : `item : Cappuccino`

MY code:

```
import pandas  as pd
import re
def ccd():
    List1 = ['Cappuccino','Café Latte','Expresso','Macchiato ','Irish coffee '],
             
    for i in range(len(List1)):
        List1[i] = List1[i].upper()
    
    txt = input('Enter a substring: ').upper()
    words = txt

    matches = []
    sentences = re.split(r'\.', txt)
    keyword = List1[0]
    pattern = keyword 
    re.compile(pattern)

    for sentence in sentences:
        if re.search(pattern, sentence):
            matches.append(sentence)

    print("Sentence matching the word (" + keyword + "):")
    for match in matches:
        print (match)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex:

```
List1 = ['Cappuccino','Café Latte','Expresso','Macchiato','Irish coffee']
         
for i in range(len(List1)):
    List1[i] = List1[i].upper()

txt = input('Enter a substring: ').upper()

matches = []
sentences = txt.splitlines()
keyword = List1[0]

for sentence in sentences:
    if keyword in sentence:
        matches.append(keyword)

print(f'Sentence matching the word (" + {keyword} + "):')
for match in matches:
    print (match)
```

Example output:

```
Enter a substring: I want 1 Cappuccino.
Sentence matching the word (" + CAPPUCCINO + "):
CAPPUCCINO
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
List1 = ['Cappuccino', 'Café Latte', 'Expresso', 'Macchiato', 'Irish coffee']

inp = 'I want 1 Café Latte'
x = [i for i, x in enumerate('#'.join(List1).upper().split('#')) if x in inp.upper()]
print(f"item: {List1[x[0]]}" if x else "item: nothing :(")
```

Output:

```
item: Café Latte
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building a regex alternation based on the list of keywords:

```py
List1 = ['Cappuccino','Café Latte','Expresso','Macchiato ','Irish coffee ']
regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(List1) + r')'
sentence = 'I want 1 Cappuccino'
matches = re.findall(regex, sentence)
if matches:
    print('Found keywords: ' + ','.join(matches))  # Found keywords: Cappuccino
```